# Windows Sed escape >< characters

Tags: regex, windows, sed, cmd

Simple question, let's say I have the following bit of text:

```
"websitedata://somenumber:1111022001"><property=something
```

Using Windows Sed I want to be able to print just the number 1111022001 and pipe that to a file, so I do the following:

```
sed -n "s/.*\"websitedata:\/\/somenumber:\(.*\)\"><property=something.*/\1/p" filename > output_filename
```

It's failing because it still see the first > there and says unexpected > at this time, if I use ^ to escape the >< then Sed sees the last > as another command and fails, also using \ to escape >< throws up a path error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: this is on Windows using Sed, not Linux, tags fixed.

Comment: Yeah, but you had this tagged `bash`.  You can run `bash` on Windows too, and then your quoting would be correct; so it's actually a question about how to quote in `cmd`, not so much about `sed`.  (I have no idea how to fix quoting in `cmd`, I just know it's murky; sorry.)

Comment: Yeah I know, unfortunatley for the scenario im working with, starting up a bash environment is not an option.

Comment: Sorry, but the `sed` command in the question is working correctly for me under windows, using both the `gnuwin32` and the `msys` versions. What `sed` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#.*:\([0-9]*\)".*#\1#' filename
```

assuming your sample data is still the same structure (so no error or corresponding condition)

Comment: Converted to Windows is sed "s#.*:\([0-9]*\)\".*#\1#", this works for the sample being in a file, but that sample I gave is part of a file with a lot more text inside it with the same characters, so I'd need to grab that first instance of that specific string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me the only option was to break it down into 2 sed commands rather that one, first one:

```
sed -i "s/[></"]//g" filename
```

That removed all the >, < and " characters, then it was

```
sed -n "s/.*websitedata:\/\/somenumber:\(.*\)property=something.*/\1/p" filename > output_filename
```

Originally wanted to keep it on one line but this works so it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape both `>` **and** `<` (using `^` the escape character) as they are both redirections symbols.

Replace `><` with `^>^<`.

---

**"when I use ^>^<, the last > which tells cmd to pipe the output to a file is failing, sed is reading that as another argument."**

You can use the `-i[SUFFIX]` or `--in-place[=SUFFIX]` command line option instead of `> output_filename`

This will change the original file and optionally make a backup.

---

Source [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> **Escape Character**
>
> `^`  Escape character.
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
>   treated as ordinary text.
>
> When piping or redirecting any of these characters you should prefix
>   with the escape character: & \ < > ^ |
>
> ```
>  e.g.  ^\  ^&  ^|  ^>  ^<  ^^
> ```

---

Source [sed, a stream editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed)

> `-i[SUFFIX]`
>
> `--in-place[=SUFFIX`
>
> This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU sed
>   does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file
>   rather than to the standard output.1.
>
> This option implies `-s`.
>
> When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed to
>   the output file's original name. The extension, if supplied, is used
>   to modify the name of the old file before renaming the temporary file,
>   thereby making a backup copy2).
>
> This rule is followed: if the extension doesn't contain a *, then it
>   is appended to the end of the current filename as a suffix; if the
>   extension does contain one or more * characters, then each asterisk is
>   replaced with the current filename. This allows you to add a prefix to
>   the backup file, instead of (or in addition to) a suffix, or even to
>   place backup copies of the original files into another directory
>   (provided the directory already exists).
>
> If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten without
>   making a backup.

Comment: Yeah I said that's what I did in the original post, but I want to pipe the command out to a file, so when I use ^>^<, the last > which tells cmd to pipe the output to a file is failing, sed is reading that as another argument.

Comment: @KishanKaplan answer updated to address your comment.